# Intellij wont let me run project inside a directory of projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, directory-structure

I have a folder which contains many projects. All of them run in intellij when I open the root folder of any particular project. However, I'm switching between many projects very often so I opened the parent directory of all my projects in intellij which lets me view all the projects contained in that directory but none of them are runnable.

Intellij also added a .idea folder inside my parent directory, so it must be assuming that the parent is a project, but it's not -- it's just a container. Is there a project structure setting I can change so that all of my projects inside the parent can be run?

Here is a visual of my structure:

```
+ AllMyProjects
    + .idea (<--- this folder was auto generated and does not belong)
    + Project1
        + .idea
        + src
            + main
                + java
                    + package
                        - MyClass.java (runnable)
            + test
    + Project2
    + Project3
```

UPDATE: SOLVED

What worked for me was (with the entire directory of projects in explorer)

File |-> Project Structure |-> Modules (Under **Project Settings**) |-> + (Add) |-> Import Module |-> (Select the module you want to run) |-> Ok |-> Import module from external model with Maven |-> Finish and Apply (Make sure the correct SDK is selected).

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: I would recommend reading up on [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) for building/running multiple modules project.

Comment: How are you running MyClass.java? Is it run using the run icon from intelliJ? Does it needs any VM args?

Comment: You can add other projects as modules into existing opened project. Note that settings that you defined in those projects only (like Run/Debug Configuration, code styles, Editor Colors etc) will not be applied. Check this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html